# Make always reverts to old version

Tags: android, linux, gnu-make, ubuntu-16.04, android-source

I'm building Android on an Ubuntu 16.04. To get the build working on 16.04 make 3.81 is required. I installed the older version through dpkg

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/make_3.81-8.2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

But now and then make is reverted back to version 4.1 just from alone. There's  no special event like reboot for this to happen. When i just run dpkg again everything is ok. Its really annoying sometimes I'm looking in my code for errors, without noting its just the wrong make version again. 
Anyone have an idea how to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your Ubuntu installation is set up to automatically apply the latest updates when available? If so, a new package version of make in the ubuntu repo might trigger an upgrade.

So, what you need to do is to lock the 'make' package to a specific version. This page describes how to do that:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package

I think the right tag for this question would be 'dpkg' or 'apt-get'.